# Visual Glitch When Drawing Rects

Tags: tiles, pygame, scrolling

I have the following code:

```
import pygame,random

pygame.init()
screen=pygame.display.set_mode((480,360))

map=[]
for y in range(32):
    row=[]
    for x in range(32):
        row.append(random.randint(0,2))
    map.append(row)

camera=[0,0]
running=True

while running:
    screen.fill((255,255,255))
    for y in range(32):
        for x in range(32):
            tile_position_x = (x*16)-camera[0]
            tile_position_y = (y*16)-camera[1]
            pygame.draw.rect(screen,(255,0,0),(tile_position_x,tile_position_y,tile_position_x+16,tile_position_y+16))
    pygame.display.flip()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running=False
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                camera[1]-=10
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                camera[1]+=10
            elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                camera[0]-=10
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                camera[0]+=10

pygame.quit()
```

When running this I find that when you scroll a few pixels in any direction the screen looks like this:

[image: visual glitch.]

Notice the long unsightly white line on the left side. Why is that there? I've read and reread all of my code and it doesn't make any sense why these problems are happening. My only explanation would be that there is some kind of rounding problem going on in my code. But I haven't found any.

Answer (score 1):

The rect argument to `pygame.draw.rect` has the form `(left top, width, height)` not `(left, top, right, bottom)`.

A quick fix is to modify the call to it to look like:

```
pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255,0,0), pygame.Rect(tile_position_x,tile_position_y,16,16))
```

Comment: Thanks! :) I always thought it was the other way around! But then again I haven't used pygame in a long time.